# GeoServer is deleting my shapefiles when I upload them

Tags: layers, geoserver-rest-api, create

- GeoServer version: 2.17.2
- Host: GCP e2-medium (2 vCPUs, 4 GB memory)
- Disk: Standard Persistent Disk 100GB
- OS: Debian, Debian GNU/Linux, 10 (buster), amd64 built on 20200902

I am uploading a zip file to the `workspaces/<workspace_name>/datastores/<datastore_name>/file.shp` endpoint as described in [the docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/stores.html#uploading-a-shapefile). My zip file contains a `.shp`, `.shx`, `.dbf` and `.cpg` file. Sometimes it works fine, but other times I can see that the files are momentarily written to the GeoServer's file system, then deleted. In their place is only a `.fix` file of the same name, which the GeoServer must have created itself.

The response from the `PUT` is `201 Created` and the Geoserver log outputs:

```
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/traffic/datastores/test2/file.shp, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/traffic/datastores/test2/file.shp, QueryString: null'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/traffic/datastores/test2/file.shp, QueryString: null'; against '/'
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/traffic/datastores/test2/file.shp, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/traffic/datastores/test2/file.shp, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/traffic/datastores/test2/file.shp, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/traffic/datastores/test2/file.shp, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/traffic/datastores/test2/file.shp, QueryString: null'; against '/rest/**'
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /rest/workspaces/traffic/datastores/test2/file.shp, QueryString: null with /rest/**
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache found an entry for basic, admin:bfa584f5598433a3c1fe16b00acc9c43
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/rest/workspaces/traffic/datastores/test2/file.shp'; to: '/rest/workspaces/traffic/datastores/test2/file.shp'  and httpMethod= PUT
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [GET]
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/rest/workspaces/traffic/datastores/test2/file.shp'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=false
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [POST, DELETE, PUT]
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/rest/workspaces/traffic/datastores/test2/file.shp'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=true
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - returning ADMIN
DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 17 locking in mode WRITE
DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 17 got the lock in mode WRITE
INFO [org.geoserver.rest.catalog] - Using existing datastore: test2
DEBUG [org.geoserver.rest.catalog] - Adding features to example
TRACE [org.geoserver.config] - org.geoserver.catalog.event.impl.CatalogBeforeAddEventImpl@5f570e0 :handlePreAddEvent
DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisting feature type example
DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33 to workspaces/traffic/test2/example/featuretype.xml
DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43 to global.xml
DEBUG [org.geoserver.catalog.impl] - Warning, some code is setting the LayerInfo name, but that will be ignored
DEBUG [org.geoserver.catalog.impl] - Warning, some code is setting the LayerInfo enabled flag, but that will be ignored
DEBUG [org.geoserver.catalog.impl] - Warning, some code is setting the LayerInfo enabled flag, but that will be ignored
TRACE [org.geoserver.config] - org.geoserver.catalog.event.impl.CatalogBeforeAddEventImpl@50e66945 :handlePreAddEvent
DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisting layer example
DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35 to workspaces/traffic/test2/example/layer.xml
DEBUG [org.geoserver.gwc.layer] - Handling add event: LayerInfoImpl[example, resource:FeatureTypeInfoImpl[example]]
DEBUG [org.geoserver.gwc.layer] - Depersisting GeoServerTileLayerInfo from gwc-layers/LayerInfoImpl-519bb9b_175e2d22e88_-7ff6.xml.tmp
DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43 to global.xml
INFO [org.geoserver.rest.catalog] - Added feature type example
DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 17 locking in mode WRITE
DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 17 releasing the lock in mode WRITE
DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

As far as I can tell, it consistently fails for some datastores, and consistently succeeds for other datastores (using the same zip file).

EDIT: I have just seen it do something even worse - successfully upload the new layer, but delete shapefiles in the same directory belonging to a different layer!

Comment: So you want to update the source data for an existing layer by changing the shapefile into new one, right? Does the new shapefile have the same attributes as the original had?

Comment: please turn logging up to GEOTOOLS_DEV and try again, then add the relevant part of the log to the question using the [edit] link. Can you also add details of your operating system and what sort of disk you are storing the data on

Comment: Thank you @IanTurton - I have added those details to the post

Comment: @user30184 - no, I am creating a new layer but in an existing datastore.

Comment: but `Feature type network_loads_7days already exists in namespace traffic, attempting to rename` says it already exists

Comment: @IanTurton - right, understood. I think that's because I tried the same upload multiple times while I was testing. I have pasted new logging output to show a better example where I tried to upload a brand new layer. The outcome was the same (only a .fix file present in the directory).

Comment: A shapefile datastore can only contain one shapefile, so I would kind of expect this to fail but it should be clearer what it is doing I guess.

Comment: @IanTurton but the datastore is of type "Directory of spatial files (shapefiles)"

Comment: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/vector/directory.html